# Как получить код скомпилированный компилятором? VS C++, GCC

Tags: gcc, c++, visual-studio

Приветствую всех, меня заинтересовала эта тема,( и похоже не одного меня, в посте [Странная компиляция](URL) посоветовали задать новый вопрос)  как можно получить скомпилированный код компилятором? В частности интересуют компиляторы Visual Studio и gcc. Да и очень хотелось бы интересных примеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как получить ассемблерный код в VS - смотри [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235426%28VS.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

в GCC
    $gcc super_proga.c -S